# jquery append multi selectbox with different name

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html code, I want that when I click on `Add More` button then append `div` and select box with different name like `name=data[Productpricemaster][30][attributeunitids]` and `name=data[Productpricemaster][31][attributeunitids]`

```html
<div class="topdivdata">
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid">
    <select id="2" name="data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue">
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="4">KG</option>
      <option value="5">MG </option>
      <option value="6">GM </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid">
    <select id="3" name="data[Productpricemaster][11][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue" >
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="7">Red </option>
      <option value="8">Green </option>
      <option value="9">Blue </option>
      <option value="10">Yellow </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; "></div>
</div>
<div id="addnewunit"style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid"> <span class="btn btn-xs cic"> <i class="icon-plus"> </i>+ Add More </span> </div>
<div id="addmoreunit" style="margin-top:30px"> </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js" type="text/jscript"></script> 
<script>
unitcount=1;
$('#addnewunit').click(function()
   {
    var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html(); 
$('#addmoreunit').append('<div>.'+topdiv+'.<div class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></div></div>'); 
 
 unitcount++;
             var value = $('.target').val();
    $('.list').val(value);
    $('.removes1').click(function()
     {
      $(this).parent().remove();
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you code is working fine except dynamic ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added blow two line that will dynamically introduce ID and name attribute to select.

```
 $($('#addmoreunit').children().last().find('select')[0]).attr('id', (unitcount + 1)).attr('name', 'data[Productpricemaster][' + (unitcount + 1) + '][attributeunitids]');
 $($('#addmoreunit').children().last().find('select')[1]).attr('id', (unitcount + 2)).attr('name', 'data[Productpricemaster][' + (unitcount + 2) + '][attributeunitids]');
```

FInal Code snipped is

```
<div class="topdivdata">
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid">
        <select id="1" name="data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="4">KG</option>
            <option value="5">MG </option>
            <option value="6">GM </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid">
        <select id="2" name="data[Productpricemaster][2][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="7">Red </option>
            <option value="8">Green </option>
            <option value="9">Blue </option>
            <option value="10">Yellow </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="addnewunit" style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid">
    <span class="btn btn-xs cic"><i class="icon-plus"></i>+ Add More </span>
</div>
<div id="addmoreunit" style="margin-top: 30px">
</div>
<script>
    unitcount = 2;
    $('#addnewunit').click(function () {
        var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html();
        $('#addmoreunit').append('<div>.' + topdiv + '.<div class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></div></div>');
        $($('#addmoreunit').children().last().find('select')[0]).attr('id', (unitcount + 1)).attr('name', 'data[Productpricemaster][' + (unitcount + 1) + '][attributeunitids]');
        $($('#addmoreunit').children().last().find('select')[1]).attr('id', (unitcount + 2)).attr('name', 'data[Productpricemaster][' + (unitcount + 2) + '][attributeunitids]');
        unitcount = unitcount + 2;
        var value = $('.target').val();
        $('.list').val(value);
        $('.removes1').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks friend one thing more select box quantity not fixed sum times it's 2 , 3 or 4 so how cane we do it

Comment: Set unitcount= total select in a row; and unitcount = unitcount + total select in a row;

Comment: dear friend  topdiv = topdiv.replace("name=\"data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]\"", "name=\"data[Productpricemaster][30][attributeunitids]\"")    , in data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids] value of [1] is not fixed sum time it's 4,5,7,9 so how cane we replace name, how cane we avoid[1] and relapse all thing

Answer (score 0):

After this line `var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html();`
add this:

```
topdiv = topdiv.replace("name=\"data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]\"", "name=\"data[Productpricemaster][30][attributeunitids]\"")
topdiv = topdiv.replace("name=\"data[Productpricemaster][11][attributeunitids]\"", "name=\"data[Productpricemaster][31][attributeunitids]\"")
```

You can replace with any string you want.

```html
<div class="topdivdata">
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid">
    <select id="2" name="data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue">
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="4">KG</option>
      <option value="5">MG </option>
      <option value="6">GM </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid">
    <select id="3" name="data[Productpricemaster][11][attributeunitids]" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 selectedvalue" >
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="7">Red </option>
      <option value="8">Green </option>
      <option value="9">Blue </option>
      <option value="10">Yellow </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; "></div>
</div>
<div id="addnewunit"style="width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid"> <span class="btn btn-xs cic"> <i class="icon-plus"> </i>+ Add More </span> </div>
<div id="addmoreunit" style="margin-top:30px"> </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.js" type="text/jscript"></script> 
<script>
unitcount=1;
$('#addnewunit').click(function()
   {
    var topdiv = $('.topdivdata').html();
topdiv = topdiv.replace("name=\"data[Productpricemaster][1][attributeunitids]\"", "name=\"data[Productpricemaster][30][attributeunitids]\"")
topdiv = topdiv.replace("name=\"data[Productpricemaster][11][attributeunitids]\"", "name=\"data[Productpricemaster][31][attributeunitids]\"")


$('#addmoreunit').append('<div>.'+topdiv+'.<div class="removes1"><span class="btn btn-xs"><i class="icon-plus"></i>- Remove</span></div></div>'); 
 
 unitcount++;
             var value = $('.target').val();
    $('.list').val(value);
    $('.removes1').click(function()
     {
      $(this).parent().remove();
     });
   });
</script>
```